# Troubles with my open id provider. How to debug?

Tags: debugging, openid

I have my own openid provider on my website, with phpmyid. It worked flawlessly until now, but apparently now it's not working anymore. I am unable to login anywhere I tried. How can I debug what's going on, to understand where's the problem ?

I can add more details if required, but if I can figure it out by myself without having to paste stuff it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Without any details, all I can say is read the logs (if phpMyID provides any), and capture the browser redirects with something like TamperData to see if there's anything obviously wrong there.

You could also try http://test-id.org/